# Can't play m3u8 file using react-hls-player npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I create a m3u8 file using ffmpeg, I need to play that file, for that i used a npm package called react-hls-player but it is not playing, what the mistake i make, below is my code

I used below code to create a m3u8 file using ffmpeg in nodejs

```
    const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
const ffmpegInstaller = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg')


ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path)

ffmpeg('uploads/malayalam.mp4').addOptions([


 
  '-c:a',
  'aac',
  '-ar',
  '48000',
  '-b:a',
  '128k',
  '-c:v',
  'h264',
  '-profile:v',
  'main',
  '-crf',
  '20',
  '-g',
  '48',
  '-keyint_min',
  '48',
  '-sc_threshold',
  '0',
  '-b:v',
  '2500k',
  '-maxrate',
  '2675k',
  '-bufsize',
  '3750k',
  '-hls_time',
  '4',
  '-hls_playlist_type',
  'vod',
  '-hls_segment_filename',
  'uploads/video/720p_%03d.ts'
  
]).output('uploads/video/output.m3u8').on('end',(err,data)=>{
  console.log(data)
  console.log('end')
}).run()
```

below is the screenshot of my m3u8 file directory

[image]

I used react-hls-player to play the m3u8 file my nodejs server running on *port:5000*

below is the reactjs code

```
    import React from 'react'
import ReactHlsPlayer from 'react-hls-player';

function M3u8_player() {
  return (
    <div className="userlist">
       
      
        <ReactHlsPlayer
    src="http://localhost:5000/uploads/video/output.m3u8"
    autoPlay={false}
    controls={true}
    width="100%"
    height="auto"
  />
  </div>
  )
}

export default M3u8_player
```

**Here i cant play the m3u8 file someone please help me , is there any mistake i made creating m3u8 file**

Comment: some one please help me out this.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Can you play the transcoded videon in VLC?

Comment: i cant play in vlc

Comment: Any error message from ffmpeg? Maybe add a console.log for the err variable at the 'end' event

Comment: no ffmpeg not giving any error

Comment: br ffmpeg not showing any error , do you have telegram act if you share your telegramid i will ping

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem that you need to pass an Authentication header within the hls player